# Android PreferenceActivity greyed out

Tags: android, xml

I programmed my PreferenceScreen without worries until I tested it. All Preferences are greyed out!

I used code from another app of mine and everything looks fine there (black text color and stuff) but in this one: Grey.

Can someone explain this weird behavior to me?

XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preferences_import_export_category">

        <Preference
            android:key="prefExportButton"
            android:title="@string/preference_export_movies"
            android:summary="@string/preference_export_movies_summary"
            android:shouldDisableView="false"
            android:selectable="true"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <Preference
            android:key="prefImportButton"
            android:title="@string/preference_import_movies"
            android:summary="@string/preference_import_movies_summary"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>


    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preference_about_category">
        <Preference
            android:key="prefInfoField"
            android:title="@string/preference_about"
            android:summary="@string/preference_about_summary"/>

       <!--<Preference
            android:key="prefInfoLoveField"
            android:title="@string/pref_about_title"
            android:summary="@string/pref_about_summary"/>-->
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Everything's grey.]

But it should look like:
[image: Everything fine]

Comment: Are they grey or greyed out i.e deactivated? It looks more like a styling issue because the titles are grey as well. Is the style in this new app different from the last? Missing a couple of style customisations?

Comment: The style is different, now I'm using material design. But I noticed no other changes, did not modify styles and can't find any stuff on the Internet regarding this

Comment: If you have a custom style (generally in styles.xml) try adding <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item> to it where black is defined <color name="black">#000000</color>. You can also replace "android:textColorPrimary" with "android:textColorSecondary" for the descriptions or "android:textColor" for a more general colour change. If you don't have a custom style set I'll post a proper answer with a little breakdown of how to do that (if google hasn't already done it).

Comment: @SebAndraos I added `<color name="textColorPrimary">#000000</color>` to color.xml and `<item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>` to styles.xml. Now my preferences are black and all fine but this caused problems on other places: The hidden settings button (in the action bar; behind the obligatory three dots) is now black text on dark grey standard background and my tab titles (I'm using swipe navigation) are now also black.)

Comment: And instead of "android:textColor", what happens if you set "android:textColorPrimary"?

Comment: @SebAndraos Nothing. Everything stays the same. Preferences grey.

Comment: Strange, I guess the next solution is to have a separate style for your PreferenceScreen. I'm not sure how you have it set up but if it's in its own activity this pretty easily through the manifest <activity
            android:name=".PreferenceActivity"
            android:theme="@style/someNewPreferenceStyle"> otherwise I'll have to knock a quick version up tomorrow to test some other solutions.

Comment: Good idea, but breaks it completely. So I've added the toolbar to the preference activity to navigate up, and if I apply the theme (contains only the textcolor) it crashes when I try to open the settings (can't inflate toolbar and stuff). When I comment out the toolbar everything looks weird with black textcolor on black background .

I don't understand this!

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm afraid without all the subtleties of your project I'm unable to replicate this failure and honestly even with them I think we've exhausted my repertoire. It sounds like time for some debugging to find out why changing the textColor is crashing an entire app.